# Responsive Menu - how to?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, menu, responsive-design

I am building a quite simple responsive menu and Ive got some trouble rearranging the submenus. So basically I have 4 menu points. 3 of them have submenus, one is just a hyperlink. The arrangement of the menu is bound to the screen width:

wide screens:

```
menu point 1 | menu point 2 | menu point 3 | menu point 4
```

submenus should appear on the bottom of the whole thing

mid screens

```
menu point 1 | menu point 2 
menu point 3 | menu point 4
```

submenus should appear right underneath the chosen menu point, so if I click on point 2, the submenu should appear in between the 2 menu lines

smallest screns

```
menu point 1
menu point 2
menu point 3
menu point 4
```

same as mid screens, menu should appear right underneath the chosen point.

so my code for the menu actually works for mid screens only:

```
<ul id="mainMenu">
  <li>menu point 1 (just hyperlink)</li>
  <li>menu point 2</li>
  <ul id="subMenu2">
    <li> ... </li>
  </ul> 
  <li>menu point 3</li>
  <li>menu point 4</li>
    <ul id="subMenu3">
      <li> ... </li>
    </ul> 
    <ul id="subMenu4">
      <li> ... </li>
    </ul> 
 </ul>
```

basically the lists subMenu2, subMenu3 and subMenu4 have to be at different positions for different screen sizes, so this version would work for smallest screens:

```
<ul id="mainMenu">
  <li>menu point 1 (just hyperlink)</li>
  <li>menu point 2</li>
  <ul id="subMenu2">
    <li> ... </li>
  </ul> 
  <li>menu point 3</li>
    <ul id="subMenu3">
      <li> ... </li>
    </ul> 
  <li>menu point 4</li>
    <ul id="subMenu4">
      <li> ... </li>
    </ul> 
 </ul>
```

I am not even sure if this is the right approach!? Any hint is greatly appreciated.

Greetings,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style any element at a given screen size using media queries. Just do something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px /* Or whatever size you want */) {
   .myElement {
      /* Styles go here */
   }
}
```

Using this approach, you can change the position of the sub-menus based on screen size. Also, have you looked into using dropdown menus? Here are some helpful links:

- Media queries: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
- How to build a dropdown menu: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp

**Edit:**

Here's a working example of completely changing the position of a div based on screen size:

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  div {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Hudson_Taylor11/pen/ZeNXwz)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know how the media css works (at least the basics), but I dont know how I can change the entire position of a list or a div block with that. Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, I'll add an example to help illustrate. Hopefully, I'm understanding your question. Just let me know if I'm way off :P

Comment: that looks good. I feel it will be kind of tricky to rearrange elements vertically. I will let you know :) (also quite new to css)

Comment: Just remember that absolute elements ignore all other elements. This sometimes makes it easier when you're trying to rearrange items. Good luck!